# How to replace the html or the return value in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can i display the return result after ajax make an request.

So it can be a solution where i can just replace the table value or replace the page without being reloaded

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchform").on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home',
                type: 'post',
                data: {contentSearch: $('#contentSearch').val()},
                success: function (data) {
                // what should i do here so it replace the page and display
                // the result result without being reloaded
                },
                error: function(){
                alert('error!');
                }
            });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html code ---

```
<form method="post" id="searchform">
        <div align="center" class="col-md-10">
            <input  type="text" id= "contentSearch" name="contentSearch" >
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch">
            Search
        </button>
</form>
```

and the result or the value should be display is rendering to the twig/html file as `chrisvalues`

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:Content:content.html.twig', array(
                    'chrisvalues' => $chrisvalues,
                        )
        );
```

The return value can be display in a table or just as a plain html as well. Where it will be replace overtime when we make a request with ajax

Anyone knows any solution to this problem !!
Desperately need some help on this, thanks a lot in advanced

Comment: What's the id of the html element you show the data?

Comment: @Christos i display `{% chrisvalues.name%}` in the html

Comment: @ChristoferHansen We don't need this. Please see my answer. We need the id of the div in which you render your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#divId").html(data);
}
```

where `divId` is the id of the div, whose content want to be replaced with the returned data.

Comment: thanks you so much for your great answer, but i have a small problem, i have create a new div like `<div id="displayResult" name="displayResult"` for displaying the result, but when it display the result, it also create a new search button and text box

Comment: how can i stop that duplication

Comment: @ChristoferHansen you are very welcome. I am glad that I helped. You can avoid this, by having this div outside of your form and rendering there only the corresponding results.

Comment: i have done that outside of the form <div id="displayResult"> and still it is creating the from in the page again when displaying the result, how can i solve that can you kindly show me an example if possible, please

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Then the problem relies on the data you return. Are you sure that the data doesn't contain the form? If it does, then you should remove it and you will get that you want.

Comment: yes i am sure the data does not create a form but it is still creating a new form, and also if the result is 4 values, it displays 4*4 times